# Setting Activities' Background Color

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change all of my activities' background color from white to black. I have tried everything - changing windowBackground, colorBackground, background but nothing seems to be working and I know my style is working because if I changed primary, accent colors they seem to be changing. The background tag only changes the action bar's color. Here's my code for the theme (what I have so far) -

```
<style name="Yoyo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent1</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/darkBackground</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/darkBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

darkBackground is black - what I need for my app to show but its not showing.

Also, I have already tried using @drawable/my_drawable_file (in which I set black color) in windowBackground but even that doesn't work.

min sdk version - 21, target sdk version - 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind people, I was just being stupid, I had hard-coded the colour for the said activity in the XML file, as soon as I removed the line which was setting the colour from XML the windowBackground started working!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change background your activity root element. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="your_color">
```

Comment: I want to dynamically change my theme, I have one more theme that's set at the beginning and then I am changing my app's theme to this style in the java code.

Comment: Create new style and change it in runtime.  For example  setTheme(R.style.your_style);

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<color name="custom_theme_color">#000000</color>
<style name="CustomTheme"Parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

and then use the custom theme in your manifest

Comment: this does not work :( As before, my theme is working, with all the primary colors and everything getting applied except the window background that's still unchanged and white.